# Make a function that takes an array number of groups and sparates the array into desired groups - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, math

I need to make an array of attributes

say: `var array = ['dog', 'cat', 'lion', 'tiger', 'bear', 'human', 'snake'];`

And make a function that divides this into however many groups desired.

For example, the input would be `function arrayGrouper(array, 3)`

and the output would be a string called `group 1` and `dog, cat, lion`,

`group 2` `tiger, bear`

`group 3` `human, snake`

and if i did

`function arrayGrouper(array, 2)`

it would return

```
  group 1   dog, cat, lion, tiger
  group 2   bear, human, snake
```

So far I have a for loop that could work inside this function, but I already know it won't work the way I want:

```
  var team1 = [];
   var team2 = [];
   var team3 = [];



    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
       if([i] <= Math.floor((array.length)/3))
        team1.push(array[i]);
    if ([i] > Math.floor(((array.length)/3)) && [i] <= (array.length - 3))
      team2.push(array[i]);
    if([i] > (array.length - 3))
    team3.push(array[i]);

   }
   print(team1);
   print(team2); 
   print(team3);
```

Also, I don't want to use `slice` or `splice` in the function.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a demo : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19958535/1636522. Now it surely works :D I think the result is closer to your requirements than the answer you've marked as accepted ;) See comments for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/c3DsK/1/

```
var array = ['dog', 'cat', 'lion', 'tiger', 'bear', 'human', 'snake'];   

function arrayGrouper ( array, n ) {
    var len = array.length;
    var groupBy = Math.floor(len/n);
    var firstLen = (len - (groupBy * n)) + groupBy;
    var ptr = 0;

    var strings = new Array();

    for ( var j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
        var string = "";
        var loop = groupBy;
        if (j == 0) {
            loop = firstLen;
        }
        for ( var i = 0; i < loop; i++ ) {
            string += " " + array[ptr];
            ptr++;
        }
        strings['group' + (j+1)] = string;
    }
    return strings;
}

console.log(arrayGrouper(array,2));
console.log(arrayGrouper(array,3));
```

And the output

```
[group1: " dog cat lion tiger", group2: " bear human snake"]
[group1: " dog cat lion", group2: " tiger bear", group3: " human snake"]
```

**Note:** you can access/save the groups like this

```
var group = arrayGrouper(array,2);
var group1 = group['group1'];
var group2 = group['group2'];
```

Comment: It makes sense!! So how would I edit this so that the largest group only has 1 more element than the rest? 

So say if there were 4 groups, each would have 2 elements and the smallest one would have 1?

Comment: it already does.. in case of 7 elements it will take 3 in the first and 2 2 in the next two groups

Comment: Ah you're right. This works perfect. I'd vote you up but apparently I can't afford it.

Comment: Does not work as expected for `arrayGrouper(array,5)`

Comment: @levi so what was your expected output?

Comment: @zzlalani the items should be evenly distributed. In `arrayGrouper(array,5)` the first group has 3 items, while the 2nd has 1 item.

Comment: can you please define it in the way i did in the answer under `And the output` like `[group1: " dog cat lion tiger", group2: " bear human snake"]`

Comment: `arrayGrouper(array,5)` outputs `[group1: " dog cat lion", group2: " tiger", group3: " bear", group4: " human", group5: " snake"]`

Comment: @levi i already know what it outputs, can you please tell me what it should outpput?

Comment: `[group1: "dog, cat", group2: "lion, tiger", group3: "bear", group4: "human", group5: "snake"]`. Based on OP's example output, it seems he wants the groups to be as even as possible, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @levi You're right : "So say if there were 4 groups, each would have 2 elements and the smallest one would have 1?". `arrayGrouper(array,4)` currently outputs `[group1: " dog cat lion tiger", group2: " bear", group3: " human", group4: " snake"]` which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/G988d/. Note that the use of arrays for groups is useless since you don't use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This returns your group array. (you can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/qCRAC/1)

```
function arrayGrouper(array, n)
{
    var maxlen=array.length/n;
    var result=new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++) result[i]='';
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        result[Math.floor(i/maxlen)]+=array[i].toString()+', ';
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++) result[i]=result[i].substring(0, result[i].length - 2);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `arrayGrouper(array, 2)` returns some empty strings

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a new array containing sub arrays for each group :

```
function arrayGrouper(stack, slices) {
    var remainder = stack.length % slices,
        size = Math.ceil(stack.length / slices),
        result = [],
        i = 0,
        slice;
    while (result.length < slices) {
        result.push(slice = []);
        while (slice.length < size) {
            slice.push(stack[i++]);
        }
        if (result.length === remainder) size--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage :

```
var groups = arrayGrouper(array, 2);
var team1 = groups[0]; // ["dog", "cat", "lion", "tiger"]
var team2 = groups[1]; // ["bear", "human", "snake"]
```

If you want strings instead of arrays use `join`<sup>[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)</sup> :

```
var groups = arrayGrouper(array, 2);
var team1 = groups[0].join(' '); // "dog cat lion tiger"
var team2 = groups[1].join(' '); // "bear human snake"
```

Here is a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/HS2yH/.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
function arrayGrouper(array, n) {
    var length, group = 0;
    var perGroup = Math.floor(array.length / n);
    var remain = array.length - (perGroup * n);
    var results = new Array(n);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        (results[group] || (results[group] = [])).push(array[i]);
        length = results[group].length;
        if (length >= perGroup) {
            group++;
            if (remain && length < perGroup + 1) {
                remain--;
                group--;
            }
        }
    }

    // print results
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var str = 'group ' + (i + 1) + ' ' + results[i].join(', ');
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S46cd/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var main_array = ['cat', 'dog', 'apple', 'orange'];

function grouper(arr_arg, group_num){
  var arr_length  = arr_arg.length;
  var new_group   = [];
  var groups      = [];
  var group0      = ['cat', 'dog'];
  var group1      = ['apple', 'orange'];
  var group_length;
  var i;
  var j;

  groups[0]       = group0;
  groups[1]       = group1;  
  group_length = groups[group_num].length;

  for(i = 0; i < arr_length; i += 1){
    for(j = 0; j < group_length; j += 1){
      if(arr_arg[i] === groups[group_num][j]){
        new_group.push(arr_arg[i]);
      }
    }
  }  
  return new_group;
}

console.log('Group 0 is: ' + grouper(main_array, 0));
console.log('Group 1 is: ' + grouper(main_array, 1));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XmQwb/

Comment: You have to define what the groups are in addition to adding an element to the `main_array` otherwise how would the function know how to find matches?

Comment: Your code relies on the groups being in sequence in the array and defined by a length.  @zzlani Mine searches for matches in any order.  Both are valid just depends on the need.